# DVI to Thunderbold only 1080p

Tags: display, thunderbolt, dvi

I hooked my mac mini late 2014 to my DELL U2713HM via dvi to thunderbolt (MiniDisplay Port on the monitor is used by a gaming pc)

But I can only go to 1080p resolution

[image]

Why? DVI is capable of much higher resolutions

Comment: I presume you mean Thunderbolt to DVI [signals go from the computer to the display]. Precisely what type of DVI cable is it? See the images here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector 2560x1440 needs  dual link.

Comment: that's the correct answer actually @Tetsujin

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the monitor requires a vertical frequency of at least 60 Hz and the Mac output is less than 60 Hz when going above 1080.

### References

- [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.6-late-2014-specs.html)
- [Dell](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-u2713hm_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf)
- [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp710?locale=en_US)

Comment: Ah, nice one. I never knew that. To be really picky, it will work at 59.88 ;) but my refresh rate is greyed out so I can't test any further. Interestingly, I also have the U2713H no M, more expensive Adobe '98 capable version, & that does do 60 exactly, also with no option to change, no matter what resolution I set.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKNOp.png

Answer (score 0):

I checked everything front to end. Aaaand it was the wrong cable

[image]

I didn't know there are so many different DVI versions. I just grabbed one out of my old cable box. 60 Hz don't seem to be an issue.

Bought now a proper DVI to HDMI dual-link cable and it works perfectly.